# How to add access to a host via symbolic name?

Tags: linux, networking, local-area-network, host

From one LAN I have access to the host 10.0.0.*** via symbolic name say a007, which was added to my /etc/hosts as:

```
10.0.0.*/*/* a007
```

But now I need to use this host as `a007` from another LAN and I can't do it. What should I do? Please explain to me how it works?

*I'm totally newby in a network questions, so feels free to clarify terminology.*

Comment: Are Both Networks Local? I Know You Said LAN. But Just Wanting To Be Clear. What I Mean Is Are Both Networks On The Same Router, Or The Same Internet Connection? And How Are You Attempting To Use The Use Name From The Second Network? Also, Are You Doing This Under A Windows Or A *nix Environment?
Most Of The Time Hostname/IP/Network Changes Are Not Set Until The Network Is Rebooted. Better Yet Reboot The Box. That Will Restart The Network On Nix And Win.

Comment: Can you ping `a007` using ip from this *another lan*? Or vice versa i.e.  Can you ping this *another lan's* any machine from `a007`?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to configure port-forwarding on the network router that a007 is behind.  Then, just use the IP of the router along with the specific port you are forwarding traffic to and you should be able to hit it.